# I am trying to change string using batch but getting some error

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Below is the code I am using but not getting result not getting desired result but error

```
set "OldStra=abc eft"
set NewStra=!NewStr1!


set "outputa=
for %%a in (%NewStr1a::=;%) do set outputa=!outputa!%%a-
rem Eliminate the last dash:
set outputa=%outputa:~0,-1%
echo Outputa: "%outputa%"



 pause;

for %%F in (C:\Users\rawal\Desktop\movie\"!NewStr1!"\*.*) do (
CALL ModFile %%~dpnxF OldStra NewStra

 )
```

I am getting this error

```
c:\Users\rawal\Desktop\movie>(CALL ModFile %~dpnxF OldStra NewStra )
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~dpnxF OldStra NewStra

For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: I don't know why I am getting error here                        for %%F in (C:\Users\rawal\Desktop\movie\"!NewStr1!"\*.*) do (
CALL ModFile %%~dpnxF OldStra NewStra

Comment: Is `modfile` a subroutine or a batch file? You are also referncing `NewStr1a` but it is not set, that we can see.

Comment: @foxidrive  it's a batch file.    what do you mean by not set  isn't this set   " set NewStra=!NewStr1!"  above

Comment: The variable names are different.  `NewStr1a` and `NewStra`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the code you have posted should not (cannot) give your error. Is your posted code the complete code? Or have you eliminated what you thought were irrelevent lines?

If the following line is executed outside of a FOR loop, then it will generate your error:

```
CALL ModFile %%~dpnxF OldStra NewStra
```

My guess is your actual code has an additional line that contains a `)` that is closing your FOR loop prematurly.

Whatever the cause, something is causing your CALL line to be outside the context of a FOR loop.

Comment: Actually, you are right.  I messed up with the code and there wasn't any error in this code but before this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
set "OldStra=abc eft"
set "NewStra=!NewStr1!"
set "outputa="

for %%a in (%NewStr1::=;%) do set "outputa=!outputa!%%a"
echo Outputa: "%outputa%"
pause;

for %%F in ("C:\Users\rawal\Desktop\movie\!NewStr1!\*") do (
    CALL ModFile %%~dpnxF "%OldStra%" "%NewStra%"
)
```

If `ModFile` is a internal procedure place a `:` colon after `CALL`.
Note: if this doesn't work you must show the whole Batch code.